# How can I make it so that only the last class interval is closed on the right?

Tags: r

I'm trying to close only the last class interval of this exercise below, but I don't have much knowledge in r and the last interval is opening like all the others.

## Code

```
dados <- c(350, 356, 364, 369, 371, 375, 379, 384, 392,
           350, 358, 364, 370, 371, 376, 380, 388,
           351, 359, 365, 370, 372, 376, 380, 391,
           352, 361, 365, 370, 372, 377, 381, 391,
           352, 362, 366, 371, 373, 378, 382, 392,
           354, 363, 368, 371, 374, 378, 383, 392)

limites <- seq(min(dados), max(dados), by = 6)
classes <- cut(dados, breaks = limites, right = FALSE)
freqAbs <- table(classes)
tabela <- data.frame(Classe = names(freqAbs),
                     Frequencia = as.numeric(freqAbs))

print(tabela)

#      Classe Frequencia
# 1 [350,356)          6
# 2 [356,362)          4
# 3 [362,368)          7
# 4 [368,374)         12
# 5 [374,380)          8
# 6 [380,386)          6
# 7 [386,392)          3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?cut`, there is an argument `include.lowest` which

> `include.lowest`: logical, indicating if an ‘x[i]’ equal to the lowest (or highest, for `right = FALSE`) ‘breaks’ value should be included.

You can use `right = FALSE` + `include.lowest = TRUE` to close the upper bound of the highest interval.

```r
classes <- cut(dados, breaks = limites, right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

###### Output

```r
print(tabela)

#      Classe Frequencia
# 1 [350,356)          6
# 2 [356,362)          4
# 3 [362,368)          7
# 4 [368,374)         12
# 5 [374,380)          8
# 6 [380,386)          6
# 7 [386,392]          6
```